# Kohana routing error

Tags: php, kohana-3.2

I keep getting this error:

```
Unable to find a route to match the URI: notifications/send
```

When I'm trying to access action send in notifications, but when I try access notifications it works fine..

This is my code:

```
Route::set(
    'notifications', 
    'notifications(<action>)',
    array(
        'action' => 'index|send'
    )
)
->defaults(
    array(
        'controller' => 'notifications', 
        'action' => 'index'
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `/`.

`notifications(<action>)` should be `notifications(/<action>)`